# Update input max on based on total of inputs entered in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, if-statement, state

I'm creating an App in react and I have an array parsed from a JSON file which gives me a maximum number of peripherals for each "bundle" of products. What I essentially need to happen is for the max value of the inputs to update once the maximum number of inputs has been reached so that a user cannot add any more products to the package. Would anyone know a way to do this in React/Javascript.

My Code is as follows

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import productdata from "./catalog.json";
import productSort from "./OrderDetails";


class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      BundleVal: "",
      ProductCounter: [],
      PeripheralCounter: 0,
      InstallationCounter: [],
      forenameVal: "",
      surnnameVal: "",
      addressoneVal: "",
      addresstwoVal: "",
      cityVal: "",
      countyVal: "",
      postcodeVal: "",
      phoneVal: "",
      emailVal: "",
      dobVal: ""
    };
  }

      forenameUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          forenameVal: val
        })
      };

      surnameUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          surnameVal: val
        })
      };
      addressoneUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          addressoneVal: val
        })
      };

      addresstwoUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          addresstwoVal: val
        })
      };

      cityUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          cityVal: val
        })
      };

      countyUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          countyVal: val
        })
      };
      postcodeUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          postcodeVal: val
        })
      };
      phoneUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          phoneVal: val
        })
      };

      emailUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          emailVal: val
        })
      };

      dobUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          dobVal: val
        })
      };

      installationUpdate = (val) => {
        this.setState({
          installVal: val
        })
      };

      updateBundle = val => {
        this.setState({
          BundleVal: val
        });
      };

  updateQuantity = e => {
    var pCounter = this.state.ProductCounter;
    var el = parseInt(e.target.id.split("_")[1], 10);
    pCounter[el] = parseInt(e.target.value, 10);
    this.setState({ ProductCounter: pCounter });
  };


  render() {

    let bname = null;
    let maxperipherals = null;
    if (this.state.BundleVal === "1") {
      bname = productdata.data.bundles[0].name;
      maxperipherals = productdata.data.bundles[0].maximumPeripherals;
    } else if (this.state.BundleVal === "2") {
      bname = productdata.data.bundles[1].name;
      maxperipherals = productdata.data.bundles[1].maximumPeripherals;
    } else if (this.state.BundleVal === "3") {
      bname = productdata.data.bundles[2].name;
      maxperipherals = productdata.data.bundles[2].maximumPeripherals;
    } else if (this.state.BundleVal === "4") {
      bname = productdata.data.bundles[3].name;
      maxperipherals = productdata.data.bundles[3].maximumPeripherals;
    } else {
      bname = null;
      maxperipherals = "N/A";
    }



    const BundleProducts = [].concat(productSort).map((item, i) =>
      <div key={item.id}>
        {item.id} <br />
        {item.name} <br />
        {item.description} <br />
        Installation: £{item.price.installation} <br />
        Monthly: £{item.price.recurring} <br />
        <input
          type="number"
          onChange={this.updateQuantity}
          value={this.state.ProductCounter[item.id] || 0}
          id={"product_" + item.id}
        />
        <br />
        {this.state.ProductCounter[item.id] || 0}<br />
        <hr />
      </div>
    );

    if (this.state.PeripheralCounter >= maxperipherals) {
        alert ("You Cannot Add any more Peripherals");
        this.state.ProductCounter;  
    } 


    var installationTotal = 0;  // Variable to hold your total  
      for(var t = 0, instalen = BundleProducts.length; t < instalen; t++) {
        installationTotal += BundleProducts[t].props.children[19] * BundleProducts[t].props.children[10];  
    }
    var installTotal = parseFloat(installationTotal, 10).toFixed(2)

    var recurringTotal = 0;  // Variable to hold your total 
      for(var r = 0, recurlen = BundleProducts.length; r < recurlen; r++) {
        recurringTotal += BundleProducts[r].props.children[19] * BundleProducts[r].props.children[14];  
    }
    var monthlyTotal = parseFloat(recurringTotal, 10).toFixed(2)



    this.state.PeripheralCounter = this.state.ProductCounter
      .filter(function(qty, pid) {
        pid = String(pid);
        for (var i = 0; i < productSort.length; i++) {
          var p = productSort[i];
          if (p.isPeripheral === true && p.id === pid) {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      })
      .reduce(function(count, carry) {
        return count + carry;
      }, 0);



    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Order</h2>
        Chosen Bundle: {bname}
        <br />
        Number of Peripherals: {this.state.PeripheralCounter}
        <br />
        Maximum Number of Peripherals: {maxperipherals}
        <br />
        Peripherals Installation Cost Total: £{installTotal}
        <br />
        Peripherals Monthly Cost Total: £{monthlyTotal}
        <br />
        Customer Name: {this.state.forenameVal} {this.state.surnameVal}
        <br />
        Customer Address: 
            {this.state.addressoneVal} 
            {this.state.addresstwoVal} 
            {this.state.cityVal} 
            {this.state.countyVal} 
            {this.state.postcodeVal} 
        <br />
        Customer Phone: {this.state.phoneVal} 
        <br />
        Customer Email: {this.state.emailVal} 
        <br />
        Customer Date of Birth: {this.state.dobVal} 
        <Bundle updateBundle={this.updateBundle} />
        <h3>Products</h3>
        {BundleProducts}
        <br/>
        <Customer 
        forenameUpdate={this.forenameUpdate} 
        surnameUpdate={this.surnameUpdate} 
        addressoneUpdate={this.addressoneUpdate} 
        addresstwoUpdate={this.addresstwoUpdate} 
        cityUpdate={this.cityUpdate}
        countyUpdate={this.countyUpdate}
        postcodeUpdate={this.postcodeUpdate}
        phoneUpdate={this.phoneUpdate}
        emailUpdate={this.emailUpdate}
        dobUpdate={this.dobUpdate}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


class Bundle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      BundleVal: ""
    };
  }

  updatebundle = e => {
    this.props.updateBundle(e.target.value);
    this.setState({ BundleVal: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Bundle</h4>
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="1"
          onChange={this.updatebundle}
          checked={this.state.BundleVal === "1"}
        />
        Indoor Camera RAPID
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="2"
          onChange={this.updatebundle}
          checked={this.state.BundleVal === "2"}
        />
        Alarm Only RAPID
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="3"
          onChange={this.updatebundle}
          checked={this.state.BundleVal === "3"}
        />
        Outdoor Camera RAPID
        <input
          type="radio"
          value="4"
          onChange={this.updatebundle}
          checked={this.state.BundleVal === "4"}
        />
        Build Your Own Bundle
      </div>
    );
  }
}



class Customer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      forenameVal: "",
      surnnameVal: "",
      addressoneVal: "",
      addresstwoVal: "",
      cityVal: "",
      countyVal: "",
      postcodeVal: "",
      phoneVal: "",
      emailVal: "",
      dobVal: ""
    }
  }

  updateForename = (e) => {
    this.props.forenameUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({forenameVal: e.target.value});
  };

  updateSurname = (e) => {
    this.props.surnameUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({surnameVal: e.target.value});
  };

  updateAddressone = (e) => {
    this.props.addressoneUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({addressoneVal: e.target.value});
  };

  updateAddresstwo = (e) => {
    this.props.addresstwoUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({addresstwoVal: e.target.value});
  };

  updateCity = (e) => {
    this.props.cityUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({cityVal: e.target.value});
  };

  updateCounty = (e) => {
    this.props.countyUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({countyVal: e.target.value});
  };

  updatePostcode = (e) => {
    this.props.postcodeUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({postcodeVal: e.target.value});
  };  

  updatePhone = (e) => {
    this.props.phoneUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({phoneVal: e.target.value});
  };

  updateEmail = (e) => {
    this.props.emailUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({emailVal: e.target.value});
  };

  updateDob = (e) => {
    this.props.dobUpdate(e.target.value);
    this.setState({dobVal: e.target.value});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Customer</h4>
        First Name: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updateForename}
          value={this.state.forenameVal}
        />
        <br />
        Last Name: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updateSurname}
          value={this.state.surnameVal}
        />
        <br />
        Address Line One: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updateAddressone}
          value={this.state.addressoneVal}
        />
        <br />
        Address Line Two: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updateAddresstwo}
          value={this.state.addresstwoVal}
        />
        <br />
        Town/City: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updateCity}
          value={this.state.cityVal}
        />
        <br />
        County: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updateCounty}
          value={this.state.countyVal}
        />
        <br />
        Postcode: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updatePostcode}
          value={this.state.cpostcodeVal}
        />
        <br />
        Phone: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updatePhone}
          value={this.state.phoneVal}
        />
        <br />
        Email: <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updateEmail}
          value={this.state.emailVal}
        />
        <br />
        Date of Birth: <input
          type="date"
          placeholder="type here"
          onChange={this.updateDob}
          value={this.state.dobVal}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default App;
```

And an example of the JSON file I am parsing is as follows

```
{
    "timestamp": 1502121471,
    "data": {
        "adverts": [],
        "bundles": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Bundle 1",
            "description": "Bundle 1 Description",
            "maximumPeripherals": 32,
            "available": true,
            "count": 0,  
            "price": {
                "installation": "99.99",
                "recurring": "23.99"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "bundle-one.png",
            },
            "products": ["1", "2", "3"]
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Bundle 2",
            "description": "Bundle 2 Description",
            "maximumPeripherals": 32,
            "available": true,
            "count": 0,  
            "price": {
                "installation": "99.99",
                "recurring": "23.99"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "bundle-two.png",

            },
            "products": ["1", "2", "2", "2", "2"]
        }],
        "products": [{
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Product 1",
            "description": "Product 1 Description",
            "maximumQuantity": 1,
            "isPeripheral": false,
            "isAvailable": true,
            "price": {
                "upfront": null,
                "installation": "0.00",
                "recurring": "0.00"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "product-one.png",
            }
        }, {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "Product 2",
            "description": "Product 2 Description",
            "maximumQuantity": null,
            "isPeripheral": true,
            "isAvailable": true,
            "count": 0,  
            "price": {
                "upfront": "60.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "1.25"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "product-two.png",
            }
        }, {
            "id": "3",
            "name": "Product Three",
            "description": "Product Three Description",
            "maximumQuantity": null,
            "isPeripheral": true,
            "isAvailable": true,
            "count": 0,  
            "price": {
                "upfront": "132.00",
                "installation": "9.60",
                "recurring": "2.75"
            },
            "image": {
                "file": "product-three.png",
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found a solution. Essentially I just have an array loop through the products and pick up on the total which then updates as products are added.

```
var installationTotal = 0;  // Variable to hold your total  
  for(var t = 0, instalen = BundleProducts.length; t < instalen; t++) {
    installationTotal += BundleProducts[t].props.children[19] * BundleProducts[t].props.children[10];  
}
var installTotal = parseFloat(installationTotal, 10).toFixed(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have not had a response because your description of the problem is vague:

> What I essentially need to happen is for the max value of the inputs to update once the maximum number of inputs has been reached so that a user cannot add any more products to the package

and then you have just dumped the code onto the page.  A reader would have to now study the code for a long time to:

1. Identify the "maximum number of inputs" variable (you could have called it anything).
2. Identify the "max value of inputs" variable.
3. Understand how these variables are calculated.
4. Understand how they relate to each other.
5. Identify if all the information is in the same scope or not.
6. Understand what the problem is and why you might be finding it difficult.

All this will probably mean that they have to create a React project just to understand what is happening.  Perhaps a different approach would be better so that more people will take the time to read the post.  Can you make the ask and information clearer please?

Thanks
Andrew